# Display data in row, not column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
table test1
number   color   brand   size   tiresize
-----------------------------------------
1         blue   d       5      6
3         red    b       3      3
4         red    b       3      3

table test2
number   color   brand   size   tiresize
-----------------------------------------
1         blue   d       5      6
2         blue   d       5      6
3         red    b       3      3


select count(*)
from test1

select count(*)
from test2
```

I retrieve the result below

3
3

I would like to have the result in row, not column,

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: The question looks like upvote loop. It is too easy to take attention of strong users.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select (select count(*) from test1) as cnt1,
       (select count(*) from test2) as cnt2
```